# Handling Multiple Form Actions on One View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have multiple master pages in my asp.net mvc web application... Each of the pages add,edit,view and delete functionalities.... What it does is i have to create multiple views for handling add,edit,view and delete functionalities (ie) the user has to navigate to another view to edit/view the details of a record... How to Handle Multiple Form Actions (ie) add,edit,view and delete functionalities  on One View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. You can do all those actions in just one view. The thing is that you must call the right action method in your controller.

Take a look on the link below. It shows you how to handle actions in your controller based on the button the user clicks inside a view.

[Handling 2 buttons submit Actions in a single View/Form - ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444245/handling-2-buttons-submit-actions-in-a-single-view-form-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm)

Answer (score 2):

Show this entry.

[Supporting multiple submit buttons on an ASP.NET MVC view](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/11/26/Supporting-multiple-submit-buttons-on-an-ASPNET-MVC-view.aspx)

Very cool technique!