# Call methods from different controllers inside same view

Tags: c#, ajax, forms

I would need to post a model from a view to two different actions, not in the same controller.

I've tried with ActionLink but I lose data, being the model comples, for example one of the properties is

```
public IEnumerable<Lot> Lots { get; set; }
```

The other option I've tried is what is explained here for example

[Handling 2 buttons submit Actions in a single View/Form - ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444245/handling-2-buttons-submit-actions-in-a-single-view-form-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm)

But I face the problem of having the actions in two different controllers.

I think I can do it with an ajax post, but I've read that is not recommended at all, so I'd love to hear any other option I can't think of.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I would need to post a model from a view to two different actions, not in the same controller.

Probably I don't understand what you're looking for, but here's a View that posts to actions in two controllers:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action1", "Controller1"))
{
    ...
    <input type="submit" ... />
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action2", "Controller2"))
{
    ...
    <input type="submit" ... />
}
```

This looks too simple to be what you want, so can you elaborate?

Comment: No, you probably are right and my question is very silly. But, this way would I be able to post the same model? or should I duplicate the form fields?

Comment: @mitomed, Each form would have to have all the model fields needed by its respective controller action.  So, yes, typically you would duplicate the model fields in each form.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. That was I was trying to avoid, don't know if possible though